# VST2.4 SDK Instrument click sound when a note ends and another starts

Tags: c++, audio, vst

I have been working on my VST instrument in C++ for a while now and I'm having a problem with a loud click when a note ends where another starts.

Actually the problem is there when a note ends too, but I've added a "fade out" algorithm eliminating that part out. But as soon as another note starts where another ends, there is no room for my fade out algorithm.

I have been trying to scan the output buffer to find steep loud values that will happen in a short period of time to take the click out by silence that part out, had it almoust working there for a while but hit the endzone.

The file with an image from the sequencer is uploaded here for you to hear the click in a short mp3 file on Soundcloud [click sound on sound cloud](https://soundcloud.com/kls-records/clicksound)

Someone who knows more about these things that could share some light on the subject, I know how a click filter works but I don't know how to implement it in a VST instrument like this, apparently not. What is a good method to tackle this?

Comment: You need to let the notes overlap. If you can't do that because your instrument is monophonic, you must wait for one note to fade before starting the next.

Comment: Ooops?? I think I've made a non monophonic VST out of a monophonic one, I'm mixing my notes together in the processReplace function. Taking the wave buffer adding them together, so that it can play notes simultaneously anyway. Is there another way to do it if you have set it up for non-monophonic. Am I missing something here??

Comment: I don't know the VST instrument SDK, so my previous comment may be irrelevant, but I do think you are doing something wrong with polyphony.

Comment: Does you synth have an envelope shaper?  If not, this would certainly explain the behaviour you describe.

Comment: Precisely what I need and put it in a notemaster kind of an object. That would make it much easier to handle it, I thought I could make it without it but I was wrong. Thank you both for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to diagnose these types of problems without seeing the source, and even then there's no "silver bullet" to solving quality problems with VST's. However, I can offer you a few bits of advice:

- Use a wave editor to look at a bounced output file **real** close. I mean, down to the sample level. [Ocenaudio](http://www.ocenaudio.com.br/) is one such freeware editor that can show the waveform down to a single sample. Using this along with some logging should be able to tell you exactly where the click is being generated. Combined with a tool like [MrsWatson](http://teragonaudio.com/MrsWatson.html) (disclaimer: I wrote MrsWatson), you can get very exact data about what the plugin is doing during any particular `process()` callback.
- You won't be able to "filter" out clicks, doing so will just decrease their presence but still result in a generally crappy sound. I would recommend trying to figure out the core cause of the problem.
- Sanity check: make sure that you initialize *all* variables to sane default values. Often times, uninitialized values can cause a single sample to have a bad value, thus resulting in a temporary spike (thus audible as a click).
- In the worst case, you can apply some linear interpolation to "smooth" out areas where you have very large differences between samples. However, this will only reduce nasty clicking but it may come at a cost of overall poor sound quality from your instrument.

Comment: I have recently solved this problem with an envelope shaper and polyphony that I didn't have when I wrote this question. And I must say thank you for your advices, because they just answered some other questions that I have (or had).